# Is it possible to set access_token in netlify.toml file?

Tags: netlify

[netlify](https://www.netlify.com) [command-line](https://github.com/netlify/netlifyctl) lets you specify the `access_token` either through `~/.config/.netlify` or the `-A` switch.

However I was wondering whether it'll be accepted through the `./netlify.toml` config file.

In the [docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference) there seem to be fields that suggest it might:

```
[context.production]
  environment = { ACCESS_TOKEN = "super secret", NODE_ENV = "8.0.1" }

[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  ACCESS_TOKEN = "not so secret"
```

But when I try it gives the error **"No access token found. Please login."** (from debug logs)

So, is it possible to set the `access_token` through `./netlify.toml` file, and if so what am I doing wrong?

If not, what do the `ACCESS_TOKEN` mentioned in the docs actually do, and how are they different from the `access_token` found in `~/.config/.netlify` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is it possible to set the access_token through `netlify.toml` file, and if so what am I doing wrong?

The `netlifyctl` command line sets up the `access_token` in a config file **not** an environment variable, so the `ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable would not be used by the `netlifyctl` command at the time of this answer.

> If not, what do the `ACCESS_TOKEN` mentioned in the docs actually do, and how are they different from the `access_token` found in `~/.config/netlify` file?

The `ACCESS_TOKEN` mentioned in the docs is just an example of how to set an environment variable for use in a script or build process at the time of a deploy on netlify. These two are not one in the same and have nothing to do with each other in this case. In theory, you could use the environment variable to build a script to run the `netlifyctl -A` using the environment variable to pass the access token to the command.

***NOTE:*** Do not put secret tokens into your `netlify.toml` file or `.env` files of a public repository for Netlify. In fact, be careful when using secret keys on public repositories in Netlify. These keys could be exposed by a commit or pull request by someone else or by accident. [There is an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466680/2597114) of how to build a `.env` file to create environment variables from "Build Environment Variables" section for use in build scripts in a private repository.