# Where to put secret keys in Netlify?

Tags: firebase, security, netlify

My static website uses serviceAccountKey.json containing secret key for fetching from Firebase data used for building site content. I didn't want to put it into repository. Where can I store it in Netlify? Environment variable? Any better alternative?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453493/set-environment-variable-for-build-in-netlify/48466680#48466680

Comment: I marked this duplicate because the answer below is my answer on the duplicate question. There is really no alternative at this time. If it is a public open source repository, do not use this method. Also, the answer by Zobia is my answer from the duplicate question copied verbatim :(. Writing to the .env area is not really needed unless you are using a method that needs it.